# Rails ActiveRecord nested .create! with PSQL POINT type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, geometry, rails-activerecord, spree

I'm trying to create a deeply nested object with Rails and ActiveRecord.

```
Order.create!(params)
```

That model contains a child `Address` which has a `coordinates` field of PSQL type POINT.

So when I try to create it I get the following error. I guess it's trying to load the `Address` type first by using the fields provided but gets hung up on the `coordinates` (POINT) type because there is no `=` comparison (it is done as `~=`, according to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-geometry.html).

So my question... is there any way to provide hints to ActiveRecord to help it perform this query properly or how should I work around this?

```
 Address Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."firstname" = '-' AND "addresses"."lastname" = '-' AND "addresses"."phone" = '-' AND "addresses"."coordinates" = '-74.0064172,40.7049028' AND "addresses"."address1" = '110 Wall St' AND "addresses"."address2" = '' AND "addresses"."city" = 'New York' AND "addresses"."zipcode" = '10005' AND "addresses"."state_id" = 1 AND "addresses"."country_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/services/cart/create_cart_service_decorator.rb:21:in `call'
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: point = unknown
LINE 1: ..."phone" = '-' AND "addresses"."coordinates" = '-74.006...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Here is a self-contained file to reproduce this.

```rb
require "bundler/inline"

gemfile(true) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"

  git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

  # Activate the gem you are reporting the issue against.
  gem "activerecord", "6.1.3.2"
  gem "pg"
end

require "active_record"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "logger"

# This connection will do for database-independent bug reports.
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "postgresql", database: "test-db")
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :addresses, force: true do |t|
    t.point :coordinates
  end
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class BugTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_nested_saving
    address = Address.find_or_create_by!({ coordinates: ActiveRecord::Point.new(0, 0) })

    assert address
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly typecast the param to an ActiveRecord::Point instance, which is supported since some versions ago:

```
x, y = params[:coordinates].split(',').map(&:to_f)
params[:coordinates] = ActiveRecord::Point.new(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks but it still tries to use `=` instead of `~=`, but now it puts the parenthesis around the coordinates.
```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: point = unknown
LINE 1: ..."phone" = '-' AND "addresses"."coordinates" = '(-74.00...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: What is the query you want to perform? A `create` does not perform a select.

Comment: Also, can you share the relevant part of your schema file?

Comment: I added a self-contained test above that recreates this. Seems like a bug unless there is a way for me to provide hints to active record on how to resolve this.